# Comparing two files from two revisions in git diff in git bash for windows?

Tags: windows, bash, git, git-bash

So I'm running:

```
git diff <rev-hash-1> <rev-hash-2> -- ./proj/MAP.csv
```

and all I get is blank output.

Per the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) I'm using the following command format:

`git diff [<options>] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…​]`

the directory above `./proj` is the root of the local repo where `.git` lives.

I've also tried the same command with the following paths, but it still comes back blank:

- `.\proj\MAP.csv`
- `.\proj\MAP.csv .\proj\MAP.csv`
- `./proj/MAP.csv ./proj/MAP.csv`
- `./proj/MAP.csv`
- `proj/MAP.csv`
- `proj/MAP.csv`proj/MAP.csv``

Is there anything else you need to make this work in the following version of git bash for Windows?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.19.0.windows.1
```

Comment: Nevermind, I tried the relative path to the file from the directory I was in and that worked.